# How do you toggle the active nav link in Bootstrap a navbar without writing additional javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple way to toggle the active link in a basic bootstrap navbar without writing any javascript?

Here's my navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav" ng-show="isAuthenticated">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/activity/create">Create Activity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/activity/manage">Manage Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/activity/su">Super User</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What language are you using? I can show you if its Ruby on Rails or PHP, but if its anything else then please add the appropriate tag. Also if you arent using any backend language then you have to use Javascript.

Comment: @nahtnam, I am using Javascript on both the server and client (Node.js and AngularJS mostly).

Comment: Under what circumstance? For example, on hover?

Answer (score 0):

Well, im not 100% sure (im not that good with javascript), but you could do a few if statements.

```
if($url=="/activity/create") {echo "class='active'";}
```

This is the php syntax. Try something out with JS.

BTW you are using node.js which is JS, so you wouldnt be able to do it without JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `class` attribute to `"active"` via JS. I do this with an external script, here's a snippet:

```js
setActive();

function setActive() {

    activePath = document.location.pathname; //get the url of current page

    switch(activePath) {   
    //evaluate activePath (more efficient than nested IFs)

        case "/uptime/":
        //if current page path is /uptime/
            document.getElementById('navuptime').className = "active";
            //set class of element with ID='navuptime' to "active"
            break;
            //break out of switch statement, we're all done

        case "/uptime/domain/":
        //if current page path is /uptime/domain/
            document.getElementById('navuptime').className = "active";
            //just like above, set class of element with ID='navuptime' to "active"
            document.getElementById('navdomain').className = "active";
            //also set the nested navbar element class attribute to "active"
            break;
            //break out of switch statement, we're all done

        default:
        //used if no match was found
            break;
            //i don't do anything if no match was found
    }
```

When adding a page to the site you have to update the script as well, but it's just one more `case` inside the `switch` statement.

Here is a snippet of my navbar HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse nudge-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="navwifi" href="/wifi">Guest WiFi</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a id="navuptime" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Uptime Monitoring<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="navwan1" href="/uptime/wan1">WAN 1 Connection</a></li>
                <li><a id="navwan2" href="/uptime/wan2">WAN 2 Connection</a></li>
                <li><a id="navdomain" href="/uptime/domain">Domain</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

You can see each navbar element has a unique ID for the JS to update. This method is manageable for my small site (less than 50 pages).

If page urls such as *domain.com/uptime/page.html* are used the `switch` statement won't find a match as it's written above... `document.location.pathname` would return */uptime/page.html*.

I always use an *index.html* file in each directory to keep the URL clean and my visitors only have to type *domain.com/uptime*.